# Change Row Element with Javascript While Keeping Everything in 1 Line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently using Javascript to add some text to multiple `<td>` elements of a webpage but the problem is that when I add the text, it spans 2 lines instead of 1.

How can I make it so it stays on one line, I don't mind if the element becomes wider.

[Here](http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/326198/2?stat1=O&ssort=W) is the page I am modifying and here is my code:

```
var Opp = document.querySelectorAll('td.P-xs')
for(i=0;i<Opp.length;i++){
    Opp[i].innerHTML = Opp[i].innerHTML + " - ##"
}
```

And here is what it looks like.

[image]

Is there a way to make it be on one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, you can do something along the lines of

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

**EDIT**

I noticed that in the example, there is a `<div>` inside the td, which is a block element, forcing the next text (which you are adding) to the next line.  If you do white-space: nowrap it only affects the inline (or inline block) elements. So you either need to make the div inline block, i.e.

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td div {
    display: inline-block; /* inline would also work in this case */
}
```

or via JS:

```
var Opp = document.querySelectorAll('td.P-xs');
for(var i = 0; i < Opp.length; i++){
    Opp[i].innerHTML = Opp[i].innerHTML + " - ##";

    Opp[i].style.whiteSpace = "no-wrap";
    Opp[i].firstElementChild.style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

Or you need to add your text within the div, i.e.

```
var Opp = document.querySelectorAll('td.P-xs');
for(var i = 0; i < Opp.length; i++){
    Opp[i].style.whiteSpace = "no-wrap";
    Opp[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML += " - ##";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up doing `$("td.P-xs").css("white-space", "nowrap");` outside of the loop

Answer (score 2):

For starters you adding it outside of a block element so you would need to do:

```
var Opp = document.querySelectorAll('td.P-xs')
for(i=0;i<Opp.length;i++){
    Opp[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML = Opp[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML + " - ##"
 }
```

then you can use white-space: nowrap; on the elements you don't want to wrap

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a script issue but instead a spacing issue, probably the `<td>` cells are too small and automatically display their content on two lines. In fact as shown in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndreIDK/xce309h6/) which I wrote with jQuery instead the content goes on a single line.

```
$.each($('td.P-xs'), function(){
   $(this).append(' - ##');
});
```